# Recursion Confusion - Summation Symbol

Tags: recursion

I have an assignment with **this** symbol on it: [Image of unfamiliar symbol

[image]

Basically the question asks "Write a recursive Java method which, given a positive integer n, computes and returns the sum of the integers from 1 to n as follows".

- I do not need any help on the recursion itself, I really just need to understand what that symbol means (Link Included), so I can answer the question properly.

**My Question:** What meaning does the symbol possess? What is my instructor expecting as a valid response?

**NOTE:** I do NOT want anyone to attempt to answer the actual assignment question. I ONLY want know understand what the symbol being used means and what should be returned in my recursion method.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation

Comment: I've removed the Java tag as your question is not about Java, and it invited a whole lot of people who didn't read your question but rather thought incorrectly that you were asking for the code.

Comment: Yea that was my bad... Kind of still frustrated about the whole math summation concept but I'll get it. Have also edited the title to reduce confusion and traffic.

Comment: Think of summations as for loops.  The part on the bottom is the first part, the second part is i<n, the third part is incrementing i.  Then you sum I to an accumulation variable.

Comment: Ok so the loop control variable would be the bottom (`i`). The condition is comparing the control variable (`i<n`). But are you saying that `i` is to be incremented by 1? (`i++`)

Answer (score 1):

IT is the sigma symbol which means take the sum from i = 1 to n.
so your output comes as 1 + 2 + 3 + ..... + n

This explanation is to left hand side of the equation. others are the same.

Comment: Can you explain like I'm five please? I hate when I can't answer a question because of something unrelated to the entire concept. I just want to know: Do `n` and `i` have a relation? How many returns is this question asking for?

Comment: well you think n = 10 right ?
if so Left hand side of the equation says "get the summation of 1 to 10"
right hand side says "add up 1 to 5" + "add up 6 to 10"
basically when you have summation sign there, what you have to do is, identify the variable, in your case it is ( i ) and substitute the values to i in the range which is specified. simply substitute 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 ..... until n and add up all them. got it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a summation symbol

The sum of each i starting from i = 1 to i == n equals the sum of each i starting from i = 1 to i == n/2 plus the sum of of each i starting from i = n/2 + 1 to i == n